# Kendo Grid - Line Editing Using A Drop-Down List Editor (Editing Custom Editor)

Tags: javascript, json, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using the example Telerik provided on [this page](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html) for inline editing within a Kendo UI grid and I would like to bind the inline drop-down list in the "Categories" column" to a JSON object instead of using the xml data they have in their demo. When I use JSON data, the drop-down list doesn't work. How do I bind a JSON object to the inline drop-down list? [A fully working fiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/Halcyon/z9NvF/).

Here is the JavaScript function that binds the data source.

```
function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    var categories = {
        'Category': [
            { 'CategoryName': 'Beverages', 'CategoryID': 1 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Condiments', 'CategoryID': 2 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Confections', 'CategoryID': 3 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Dairy Products', 'CategoryID': 4 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Grains/Cereals', 'CategoryID': 5 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Meat/Poultry', 'CategoryID': 6 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Produce', 'CategoryID': 7 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Seafood', 'CategoryID': 8 }
        ]
    };

    $('<input required data-text-field="CategoryName" data-value-field="CategoryID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: categories
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following.

```
var Category = 
 [
            { 'CategoryName': 'Beverages', 'CategoryID': 1 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Condiments', 'CategoryID': 2 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Confections', 'CategoryID': 3 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Dairy Products', 'CategoryID': 4 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Grains/Cereals', 'CategoryID': 5 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Meat/Poultry', 'CategoryID': 6 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Produce', 'CategoryID': 7 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Seafood', 'CategoryID': 8 }
];
```

and as the datasource use

```
$('<input required data-text-field="CategoryName" data-value-field="CategoryID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: Category
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    var categories = {
        'Category': [
            { 'CategoryName': 'Beverages', 'CategoryID': 1 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Condiments', 'CategoryID': 2 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Confections', 'CategoryID': 3 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Dairy Products', 'CategoryID': 4 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Grains/Cereals', 'CategoryID': 5 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Meat/Poultry', 'CategoryID': 6 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Produce', 'CategoryID': 7 },
            { 'CategoryName': 'Seafood', 'CategoryID': 8 }
        ]
    };

    $('<input required data-text-field="CategoryName" data-value-field="CategoryID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: categories.Category
        });
}
```

Look at the above, you need to use property to bind to the datasource. Since kendo datasource is required an Array object.